# Show images from S3 bucket into Ruby-on-Rails application

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku

I have setup an S3 bucket with name '**mobiles**' and populated it with around 2000 images. The bucket has a folder structure as well like '**mobiles / vendor-name / model-name / model-image.jpg**'.

In my rails application which I have hosted on Heroku, I want to show the list of those images against vendors and models. How can I do that ? (i mean linking them from S3 directly)

I already have saved vendors and models in Postgresql database.

I am new to RoR world so please explain the answer considering the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check that every image have the right permissions.

[image: Permissions]

Under the properties tab of every image, you could see a link to that image.

[image]

In your case is probably that looks like `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mobiles/vendor-name/model...`.

Comment: Does it have to do anything with 'paperclip' gem ? I am asking because in my application 'paperclip' is being used to add new images from admin site.

Comment: Perhaps for upload, but not for display. Once you have the link, you don't need any more things.